# Remove front and back white space and insert single quote with comma

Tags: vba

Is there a way to trim the front and back, any white spaces, and give a single quote with a comma?

```
Value
12589ABC
  A457892CD
564897ACC 
ACT456734
 BCD6589745
TA345TCFS 

Expected Result

'12589ABC',
'A457892CD',
'564897ACC', 
'ACT456734',
'BCD6589745',
'TA345TCFS',
```

Comment: Did you try using `Trim()` ?

Comment: I tried trim() function but it does not remove double space and I need to use a macro that removes front and back space with a single run for large data set

Comment: You tried Trim() in VBA?  TRIM() as a worksheet function does remove multiple spaces from the start/end of text, and reduces runs of spaces *within* text to a single space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    [ ]*(\S+)[ ]*
Replace: '$1',
```

### Demo

Sample script:

```
Dim RegEx As Object
Dim Cell As Range
Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.Pattern = "[ ]*(\S+)[ ]*"

For Each Cell In Selection.Cells
    Cell.Value = RegEx.Replace(Cell.Value, "'$1',")
Next
```

Comment: I ran the script and found this result:
`12589ABC',
A457892CD',
564897ACC',
ACT456734',
BCD6589745',
TA345TCFS',`

Comment: After I made a change, it is working as expected. Cell.Value = RegEx.Replace(Cell.Value, " ''$1',") Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen